# Carpenter of you?

Tags: of-phrases

"It's sweet of you."
I understand it as " you did a sweet thing".

"Carpenter of you." 
My head was full of question marks when I heard it on Tv.
A Japanese celebrity was making a kitchen with professional carpenters in Hawai, and a Hawaiian carpenter said it to the celebrity.

Can "of you" work that way?

Can I say "runner of you" to who run fast?
How about "chef of you " to my mum when she cooked nice foods?

Thanks!

Comment: This kind of phrase usually uses an adjective, not a noun. I would guess that the speaker was using "carpenter" as an adjective (which is not standard).

Comment: I wooden use that phrase.